# why \n in printf prints no value or old value of char array?

Tags: c, char, printf

I was trying to test named pipe when i encountered this error. 
I have a file named client.c who writes to a named pipe.
And I have a file named server.c who reads from a named pipe and print its value. 
Looks like there is some issue with server.c

Client code.

```
//-------CLIENT-----------
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"
int main()
{
    int fd, ch;
    char readbu[80];
    int write_byte;
    fd=open(FIFO_FILE,O_WRONLY);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter choice \n1.Pepsi\n2.Coke\n3.Limca\n4.Maza\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: strcpy(readbu,"Pepsi\0");  
            write_byte=write(fd,readbu,sizeof(readbu));
            break;
            case 2: strcpy(readbu,"Coke\0");  
            write_byte=write(fd,readbu,sizeof(readbu));
            break;
            case 3: strcpy(readbu,"Limca\0");  
            write_byte=write(fd,readbu,sizeof(readbu));
            break;
            case 4: strcpy(readbu,"Maza\0");  
            write_byte=write(fd,readbu,sizeof(readbu));
            break;
            default:printf("Invalid");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Server code:

```
// Server code    
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"
int main()
{
    int fd;
    char readbuf[80];
    char end[10];
    int to_end;
    int read_bytes;
    mknod(FIFO_FILE,S_IFIFO|0640,0);
    strcpy(end,"end");
    while(1)
    {
        fd=open(FIFO_FILE,O_RDONLY);
        read_bytes=read(fd,readbuf,sizeof(readbuf));
        readbuf[read_bytes]='\0';
        printf("Rec str = %s of len %d", readbuf,(int)strlen(readbuf));
        to_end=strcmp(readbuf,end);
        if(to_end==0)
        { close(fd);
            break;
        }`enter code here`
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At server side above code does not print any output.

If i change the printf statements to below then I observe that first iteration it prints blank line and then for other iteration it print old values.

```
printf("\nRec str = %s of len %d", readbuf,(int)strlen(readbuf));
```

If i change the printf statements to below then I observe that it prints correct values.

```
printf("Rec str = %s of len %d\n", readbuf,(int)strlen(readbuf));
```

I am completely confused how the \n makes so much difference.

I tried to check the value in readbuf using gdb and it actually contains the correct values.
Kindly help me understand the trick here.

Comment: If you're running on Linux, run your server process under [`strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and you'll see what's going on, especially if you use `strace` to emit what data your server process actually reads from the pipe.

Comment: `strcpy(readbu,"Pepsi\0");` What is this `\0` doing here exactly?

Comment: `stdout` in line buffered. The contents of the buffer are not displayed on the screen until a `\n` is printed. So putting the `\n` at the end of the `printf` works correctly.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have to do `fd=open(FIFO_FILE,O_RDONLY);` in every loop iteration.

Comment: @AndrewHenle when I checked in gdb I observed readbuf actually had correct data.  I understand stdout is line buffered. But any printf works if we dont put any \n there. And why it prints old values when the readbuf actually has the correct data ? from where it got the old data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output buffer is not normally flushed until it is either full, a newline is inserted, or an explicit `fflush( stdout )` call.

When you have the newline at the start of the output, it flushes the previously buffered data, and buffers the following data.

The following will resolve the issue:

```
printf("\nRec str = %s of len %d", readbuf,(int)strlen(readbuf));
fflush( stdout ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you @Clifford for this answer. It helped me a lot. I verified and it worked.